# Seleniumで同じcsvが重複して追加されてしまうのはなぜ？

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

pythonやプログラミングの初心者です。
色々なサイトを調べましたが、問題が解決されなかったため、こちらに投稿させていただいています。
基本的な内容かもしれませんが、ご協力いただけますと幸いです。

#### やりたいこと

Google Colaboratoryを使って下記のサイトに載っているリストをスクレイピングして
csvとして出力して、データ解析をしたいです。

http://regalkes.kemkes.go.id/info.php#home/produk/lstPkrt/02

このサイトを見ると、リストが複数ページに跨っていることが分かります。
そして、ページを遷移するリンクがJavaScriptになっているため、Seleniumを使用することにしました。

考えたフローは、以下の通りです。

#### フロー

1.最初に上記のサイトにアクセスして、DataFrameとしてデータを取得する。
　2.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/535tM.jpg)で取得したデータをcsv出力する。
　3.次のページに遷移して、DataFrameとしてデータを取得する。
　4.[3]で取得したDataFrameをcsvデータとして出力して、[2]で出力したcsvデータの最終行に追加する。
　5.[3],[4]の作業をforループで繰り返して、サイトに掲載されているデータをすべて追加する。
このフローに沿って、作成したプログラムが下記の通りです。

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install lxml
!pip install html5lib
!pip install beautifulsoup4
!pip install webdriver-manager

!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from google.colab import files
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time 
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv

# Chrome Driver Option
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless') # Headless Mode
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Sandbox off 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') # /dev/shmパーティションの使用を禁止

# Web Driver Set
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

# URL
URL = "http://regalkes.kemkes.go.id/info.php#home/produk/lstPkrt/02"
driver.get(URL)


#上記フローの[1],[2]
from pandas.core.describe import DataFrameDescriber
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'http://regalkes.kemkes.go.id/info.php#home/produk/lstPkrt/02'
df1 = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
df1
df1[0].to_csv('/content/output.csv')


#pagesにページ数を入力
pages = 2

for i in range(pages+1):
  #上記フローの[3]
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()
  time.sleep(1)
  df2 = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header = 1)
  df2
  df2[0].to_csv('/content/output2.csv')
  df1 = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
  #上記フローの[4]
  df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
  df1
  df1.to_csv('/content/OUTPUT.csv', mode='a', header=True)
  break
```

#### 出力結果(11/4追記)

求めている出力結果と実際の出力データはは、添付した画像の通りです。
データベース上のNo.を連番で追加していくように設定したいのですが、
同一のページのデータ（[2]で出力したcsvデータ）が"pages ="で設定した数値の数だけ繰返し追加されるようになってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

データの結合がうまくいっておりません。
ページを遷移するプログラムや、遷移したページでcsvデータを出力するプログラムは動作しているようなのですが…

お力添えいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 出来たCSVファイルの内容も提示して、どの部分がおかしいとか、どうなっていて欲しいとかの詳細を追記してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 中間ファイルを作成する必要は無いように思います。df1にdf2を追加していくだけで良いのではないでしょうか？（小文字と大文字のoutput.csvがあるのが気になりますが。また'/content/output.csv'と"output.csv"は同じパスですか？別ですか？）

Comment: @kunif
コメントありがとうございます。また、こちらの説明が不十分で申し訳ございません。実際の出力結果と求めている結果を画像にして添付しました。お手すきの際に、ご覧になっていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: @merino
コメントありがとうございます。ご提案いただいたようにdf2の"output2.csv"を作成不要と思っていたのですが、色々とエラーが生じたため、このようにしました。もし、作らずに出来る方法があれば、ご教示いただけると大変助かります。ページを遷移するごとに"output2.csv"を書き換えて、df1を"OUTPUT.csv"として新たにファイルを作って、そこにdf2を次々に追加していく方法を考えました。また、"output.csv"、"output2.csv"、"OUTPUT.csv"についてはいずれも同じパスに保存するようにしています。

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()`が上手く動作していなくて、次のページへ遷移していないのではありませんか？ そのために同じページの内容が追加されていると思われます。

Comment: @kunif コメントありがとうございます。以下のプログラムは正常に動作しており、次ページに遷移してDataFrameを取得することを確認しました。
 driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()
 time.sleep(1)
 df2 = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
 df2
 df2[0].to_csv('/content/output2.csv')
また、元のプログラム文でも繰返し追加はしているので、Forループも正しく動作していると思います。
問題はご指摘のように"driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()"がForループの中にあるときに、正しく動作していないために生じているように思います。もう少し調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

最初の問題点は、ページの遷移完了待ち時間が1秒では不足していると思われることでしょう。
どのくらいの時間が適当なのかは対象サイトの性能？やスクリプトの動作環境に依存すると思われるので実験して決めてください。

それからサイトの情報をDataFrameに入れたり、CSVファイルに書いたりする時に余計な情報が付いたままだと思われるので、それらは削った方が良いでしょう。
例えば変更箇所の該当部分は以下のようになるでしょう。

```
df1 = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header=1) #### ヘッダー行の指定を追加
#### 以下は有効なデータである先頭10行のみファイル出力。かつインデックスは不要なのでは？
df1[0].head(10).to_csv('/content/output.csv', index=False)

#pagesにページ数を入力
pages = 2

for i in range(pages+1):
  #上記フローの[3]
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()
  time.sleep(5) #### ここが一番最初の問題点で十分な待ち時間が指定されていなかった。
  df2 = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header=1)
  #### 最初と同じく先頭10行のみファイル出力。かつヘッダーとインデックスは不要なのでは？
  df2[0].head(10).to_csv('/content/output.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご教示いただいた内容に従って実施したところ、要望通りの結果を得ることができました。当初よりご丁寧に教えていただき、本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

私の環境では下記コードで取得出来ました。
※ DataFrame.append()でWarningが出たためコードを変更しています。（pandas 1.4.3）

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd
import time

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
URL = "http://regalkes.kemkes.go.id/info.php#home/produk/lstPkrt/02"
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)

pages = 2
dfs = []
for i in range(pages+1):
    dfs.append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header=1)[0])
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "›").click()
    time.sleep(2)
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

Comment: コメントいただき、ありがとうございました。ご教示いただいたプログラムを試したのですが、『driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',service=service)』の部分で、『WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.』というエラーが出てしまい、色々と調べたのですが、対処できませんでした。